# UMAP "ValueError: cannot assign slice from input of different size"

Tags: python, valueerror, runumap

I am using umap-learn 0.5.3 for dimension reduction of a Numpy array.
The array, say **arrival_tfidf**, is shaped (7898, 2969) and is a TF-IDF transformation of 7898 messages, containing float64 elements. When running the following snippet

```
import umap.umap_ as umap
umap_embeddings = (umap.UMAP(n_neighbors=15,
                             n_components=4,
                             metric='cosine',
                             random_state=42)
        .fit_transform(arrival_tfidf))
```

I get the following error

`ValueError: cannot assign slice from input of different size`

However, when using a random Numpy array of identical shape, `random_df = np.random.rand(7898, 2969)` instead of `arrival_tfidf`, everything works fine.

I noticed **arrival_tfidf** is rather sparse, namely around 100.000 elements.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue

Comment: I changed the random seed and it worked... doesn't really solve it though

Answer (score 1):

I downgraded pynndescent to 0.5.8 and that helped

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34977163)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I downgraded from pynndescent version 0.5.10 to version 0.5.8 and now it works for me.
Sparse data might have something to do with it, as my data is also sparse, and on other types of data the same code could work well.
Most of my failed configurations for UMAP was when robust scaling was used.